# What does the -s command show? and why it changes with -h?

Tags: linux, command-line

What does the the first column shows when using the `-s` command with `ls` command?

```
$ ls -als

41 -rw-r--r-- 1 user user 165287 Jul 10 11:18 '.tutorial.term'
 1 lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user     18 Jul  1 08:40  .bash_profile -> /home/user/.bashrc
 3 -rw-r--r-- 1 user user   2355 Jul  1 08:40  .bashrc
```

Does it show the number of blocks used for that file? or the size of blocks used for that file?

If I add the `-h` command to the mix, which prints sizes in a human readable format, why does the first column changes too? and why does the value differs from that in the 6th column which represents the actual size of the file?

```
$ ls -alsh

 41K -rw-r--r-- 1 user user 163K Jul 10 12:34 '.tutorial.term'
 512 lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user   18 Jul  1 08:40  .bash_profile -> /home/user/.bashrc
2.5K -rw-r--r-- 1 user user 2.3K Jul  1 08:40  .bashrc
```

Comment: Did you look at the man page for `ls`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as ls [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) says, -s will `print the allocated size of each file, in blocks`
The size of a file and the space it occupies on your hard drive are rarely the same. Disk space is allocated in blocks. If a file is smaller than a block, an entire block is still allocated to it because the file system doesn’t have a smaller unit of real estate to use. [reference](https://www.howtogeek.com/450366/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-file-or-directory-in-linux/)

also when you use, `-h` option, it will change allocated block size and file content size into bytes to be human readable. So block size can be different from file size because, it often happens that file content won't use all allocated size

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know why `ls -l` and `ls -s` give different sizes, read [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/269531/820775). Basically, `-l` returns the actual size of the file while `-s` returns the size in the filesystem. `h` makes all sizes human-readable, including the ones for `-s` and `-l`.